# Problem with ncWMS

Tags: netcdf, tomcat

I have an AWS EC2 machine running an ERDDAP server on Tomcat, and I'm trying to install ncWMS in order to be able to visualize the data. I've downloadaded the war file and copied it to the Tomcat webapps folder. However, I get the error

> Could not start the application in context path [/ncWMS2]

and, when I try to access it in the /ncWMS2 URL, I get the message

> The requested resource [/ncWMS2/] is not available

What is wrong?

Comment: `Note that you will need to configure a security role within your servlet container to be able to use this.` ~ https://reading-escience-centre.github.io/ncwms/ did you do this?